# Request: fix spelling on super-street-figher-4 tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It looks like [super-street-figher-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-figher-4) is a simple misspelling rather than a consequence of space constraints ... could someone change the tag to be [super-street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updating post history, 11 rows affected
updating posts, 8 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 8 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [super-street-fighter-4] and [super-street-figher-4] complete!
Tag Synonym super-street-figher-4 -> super-street-fighter-4 was approved!
```

Completed. ♪

I'll also take this opportunity to point out the second comment [on a certain English answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32889/what-is-the-error-called-when-two-letters-are-mistakenly-swapped/32897#32897), if people wonder how that typo got so long without anyone noticing.

> I cnduo't bvleiee taht I culod aulaclty uesdtannrd waht I was rdnaieg. Unisg the icndeblire pweor of the hmuan mnid, aocdcrnig to rseecrah at Cmabrigde Uinervtisy, it dseno't mttaer in waht oderr the lterets in a wrod are, the olny irpoamtnt tihng is taht the frsit and lsat ltteer be in the rhgit pclae. The rset can be a taotl mses and you can sitll raed it whoutit a pboerlm. Tihs is bucseae the huamn mnid deos not raed ervey ltteer by istlef, but the wrod as a wlohe. Aaznmig, huh? Yaeh and I awlyas tghhuot slelinpg was ipmorantt! See if yuor fdreins can raed tihs too. – [Unreason](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8377/unreason) Jul 5 at 13:12